# Different address while duplicating string literal

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, memory-address, string-literals

*[I am new to programming.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlUKg.png)*
 We know that iar is a pointer to the first element ie. it points to base of 1 and we stored this pointer to another pointer p in line 5. They both now point to the first element of int array. When the address they are storing is printed it is same i.e. *0x7ffe3b93f660*. 
We also know the string literal also is a pointer to the first character of the string and ar will also be a pointer to the first character of the string. If both of them are pointing to the same element than why they are returning different address i.e. *0x5565b94e700f* and *0x7ffe3b93f66c*. 
**Why is this happening why not the same address in second case also?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int iar[]={1,2,3};
    int *p=iar;
    printf("\n%p and %p",iar,p);
    char ar[]="Kurukshetra";
    printf("\n%p and %p","Kurukshetra",ar);
    printf(" %c ",*ar);
    printf(" %c ",*"Kurukshetra");
return 0;
}
```

I have also attached an image with this question showing different address on execution.

Comment: Because `char ar[]="Kurukshetra";` has created *another* (modifiable) string, and it copied `"Kurukshetra"` into it.

Comment: `char ar[]="Kurukshetra";` initializes an array by copying the data from a string literal, but it is not a string literal itself.

Comment: String literal is backed by global static array of chars while `ar` is a local variable array initialized from string literal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all using the conversion specifier `%d` with pointers is invalid.

Instead of

```
printf("%d","Kurukshetra");
```

and

```
printf(" %d",ar);
```

you have to write

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )"Kurukshetra");
```

and

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )ar);
```

The array `ar` and the string literal occupy different extents of memory. So their addresses are different.

The array `ar` was initialized by characters of the string literal by means of copying them in the extent of memory occupied by the array.

```
char ar[]="Kurukshetra";
```

You may imagine this the following way

```
char string_literal[] = "Kurukshetra";
char ar[sizeof( string_literal )];

memcpy( ar, string_literal, sizeof( string_literal ) );
```

As you see each array has its one extent of memory.

Also pay attention to that even identical string literals can have different addresses. That is the compiler can store identical string literals as one character array with static storage duration or as separate arrays. This depends on compiler options.

So for example if the compiler stores identical string literals as separate arrays then these calls

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )"Kurukshetra"); 
printf("%p\n", ( void * )"Kurukshetra");
```

can produce different values.

Form the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 **It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values.** If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined